# WPF Vb.net Delete Specific Line Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, streamreader, streamwriter

When I run the following code (in a event) to delete the string "DoNotShowSafeBootPages=Yes" I am getting this error "The process cannot access the file 'C:\cfig.ini' because it is being used by another process."

```
     Sub DeleteLineSM()
    Dim line As String = Nothing
    Dim line_to_delete As String = "DoNotShowSafeBootPage=Yes"

    Using reader As New StreamReader("C:\cfig.ini")
        Using writer As New StreamWriter("C:\cfig.ini")
            While (reader.ReadLine()) IsNot Nothing
                If [String].Compare(line, line_to_delete) = 0 Then
                    Continue While
                End If

                writer.WriteLine(line)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

All I am trying to do is delete the string mention above from the text file. Could someone help me?

Comment: I'd write it more like `var lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path); IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, lines.Except(deleteTheseLinesList));` where `deleteTheseLinesList` is a list of lines you want removed.

Comment: Well you are opening the file twice, once with the reader, once with the writer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DeleteLineSM()
 Dim lines As New List(Of String)
 Dim line_to_delete As String = "DoNotShowSafeBootPage=Yes"
 Using reader As New StreamReader("C:\cfig.ini")
    'need a looping mechanism
   While Not reader.EndOfStream
      'add to our list
     lines.Add(reader.Readline)
   End While
 End Using 
  'check if the delete text exist and then delete it
 If lines.Contains(line_to_delete) Then lines.Remove(line_to_delete)
  'overwrite the file
 Using writer As New StreamWriter("C:\cfig.ini")
    For Each line In Lines
     writer.WriteLine(line)
    Next
 End Using
End Sub
```